# Java 7 run selected method in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

In my code **Java 7** (and no cannot use Java 8+) I try to run **selected** method in thread from one class file but somehow cannot grasp how to do it for methods without any parameter passed. This is what I have so far:

Tools.java

```
public final class Tools implements Runnable {

    private int number; // necessary for checkInt(int number) to work
    private int string; // necessary for checkString(String string) to work

    public void run() {
        
    }

    public static int checkInt(int number) {
        return number;
    }

    public static String checkString(String string) {
        return string;
    }

    public static String checkNoParamString() {
        //doing some stuff
        return string;
    }

    public static String checkNoParamInt() {
        //doing some stuff
        return int;
    }
}
```

App.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread tstring = new Thread(Tools.checkString("test"));
    Thread tint = new Thread(String.valueOf(Tools.checkInt(10)));
    Thread tNoString = new Thread(Tools.checkNoParamString()); //<-does not work
    Thread tNoInt = new Thread(Tools.checkNoParamInt());  //<-does not work

    tstring.start();
    tint1.start();
    tNoString.start();
    tNoInt.start();

}
```

Can someone tell me what to do to make it work with not parameterized methods, if possible without creating new java class files for every single method or using Java 8 ?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Exceptions? Compilation errors?

Comment: @Fildor It doesn't compile because `Tools.checkString("test")` is not a Runnable.

Comment: @shmosel You and I know that. I wanted OP to add the errormessage, so we can tell him, where it says so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-Java 8 lambda equivalent would be anonymous classes:

```
Thread tstring = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Tools.checkString("test"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work and doesn't do what you think it does anyway. The `Tools.checkString()` and `Tools.checkInt()` are executed prior to running the thread; you're executing them in the main thread, and then passing the result of that into the `new Thread()` constructor: in effect, you're using those to name the threads, and not execute them.

If you want to do this in threads, then you'll need to implement four `Runnable` subclasses, and put the implementation of the body into `void run() {...}` methods instead. The fact that you've left the `run()` body empty in your code hides the failure. If you put a print in there, you'll notice that you aren't even calling that, because you're not passing an instance of `Runnable` into the `new Thread()` constructor. You'll want something like:

```
new Thread(new Tools()).start()
```